# What is the purpose of the "disciplined" badge?

Tags: support, badges

Which type of behavior is the "disciplined" badge trying to promote?
Why users who deleted their own posts, which had a score of at least three, would get a badge?

Comment: Welcome to S&M.SE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose it's for users who wrote an answer that was somewhat well-received but who later realized that their answer had some major flaw and deleted it anyway, knowing that even though they had popular support for their answer, it was wrong and so they had the “discipline” to delete the answer.

Comment: The fact of deleting an answer that had a score of +3 doesn't automatically mean the answer had a major flow, and it was correct to delete it. I understand what you are saying, but it seems (to me) to make more sense to get a badge when deleting an answer with a score of -3; in that case, the negative score could be used as a measure of the answer really having a flaw. It is true that somebody would delete a question with a score of +3 if he is not really happy with his/her own answer, and one is more "brave" when deleting an answer with a score of +3 than with a score of -3.

Comment: Another oddity is that since badges, by and large, are not revoked, you can simply delete an answer and then undelete in an hour or so after you've gotten the badge.

Comment: The title of the badge for someone who deletes their own entry with a minus 3 (or lower) is peer-pressured. On other stock exchange sites, that also has the effect of eliminating the impact of the down votes. Apparently it does not on this site.

Comment: @Tom Au: Stock exchange?  Did I detect a Freudian slip??

Comment: @drm65: No, I am better known in the "real world" for stocks than I am for the stack exchange. Specifically, for my 2004 book, "A Modern Approach to Graham and Dodd Investing," that correctly called the 1929-style stock market crash that took place in 2008-2009.

Comment: @Tom: Neat!  Though you really shouldn't have given me the title.  I am snoopy.  It doesn't take me long to get your ph# and street address from that!

Answer (score 2):

I find deleting my own answers wrong especially if others have voted on it, up or down. I feel there should remain a record of what people responded to (especially if it was downvoted, then people can see what a wrong or unpopular answer is).

I can see that deleting a high voted answer takes discipline (do you lose the associated rep?), but I don't get why it is rewarded with a badge.

Comment: Sometimes we have two (and more) identical answers posted within seconds of one another. Naturally, people upvote all of them. But it makes perfect sense to leave only one of them up. (And yes, you do lose the rep, but only upon the next rep recalc.)

Comment: @Mitch: It's just a bronze badge.  Not all of them are meant to be milestones like silver badges or gold badges.  Not everyone is in a situation to get some of the bronzies.  I don't think I'll ever get Tumbleweed, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I am contemplating deleting [my answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89839/how-do-i-determine-the-runtime-of-a-double-recursive-function/89850#89850) to a question on Programmers.SE because the original question has changed so much that my answer no longer applies.  I have four upvotes (some of which I have received since the question changed) so deleting my answer would earn the badge.  I have not deleted it yet because it helps show the confusion that can surround the entire topic of the question.